# Codeigniter query with Date functions in where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-date-functions

I am trying to convert the following SQL query into Codeigniter format.

```
SELECT tb.pickup_trip_location,
   tb.drop_trip_location,
   CONCAT_WS(' ', tp.firstname, tp.lastname) AS passenger_name, 
   tb.tkt_passenger_id_no AS tkt_passenger_id_no,
   tb.trip_id_no AS trip_id_no,
   tb.id_no AS booking_id_no,
   DATE_FORMAT(tb.booking_date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') as booking_date,
   DATE_FORMAT(tb.date, '%b %e %Y %T') as booking_time,
   tr.name AS route_name,
   tb.request_facilities AS request_facilities,
   tb.price AS price,
   tb.total_seat AS quantity,
   tb.discount AS discount,
   tb.seat_numbers AS seat_serial,
   tb.adult,
   tb.child,
   tb.special,
   tb.booking_type,
   tb.trip_route_id,
   tp.nid,
   tp.phone AS phone,
   tb.payment_status,
   fr.owner,
   fr.reg_no,
   tras.`assign_time` AS assign_time
   from tkt_booking AS tb
   join tkt_passenger AS tp ON tb.tkt_passenger_id_no = tp.id_no
   join trip_route AS tr ON tr.id = tb.trip_route_id
   join trip_assign AS tras ON tras.trip = tb.trip_id_no
   join fleet_registration AS fr ON fr.id = tb.fleet_id
   where tb.id_no = "$booking_id_no" AND
   DATE(tb.booking_date) = DATE(tras.`assign_time`)
```

I managed to write the following code but it does not return any data

```
return $this->db->select("
tb.pickup_trip_location,
    tb.drop_trip_location,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', tp.firstname, tp.lastname) AS passenger_name, 
    tb.tkt_passenger_id_no AS tkt_passenger_id_no,
    tb.trip_id_no AS trip_id_no,
    tb.id_no AS booking_id_no,
    DATE_FORMAT(tb.booking_date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') as booking_date,
    DATE_FORMAT(tb.date, '%b %e %Y %T') as booking_time,
    tr.name AS route_name,
    tb.request_facilities AS request_facilities,
    tb.price AS price,
    tb.total_seat AS quantity,
    tb.discount AS discount,
    tb.seat_numbers AS seat_serial,
    tb.adult,
    tb.child,
    tb.special,
    tb.booking_type,
    tb.trip_route_id,
    tp.nid,
    tp.phone AS phone,
    tb.payment_status,
    fr.owner,
    fr.reg_no,
    tras.`assign_time` AS assign_time
")
->from('tkt_booking AS tb')
->join('tkt_passenger AS tp', 'tb.tkt_passenger_id_no = tp.id_no' ,'full')
->join('trip_route AS tr', 'tr.id = tb.trip_route_id','full')
->join('trip_assign AS tras', 'tras.trip = tb.trip_id_no','full')
->join('fleet_registration AS fr', 'fr.id = tb.fleet_id','full')
->where('tb.id_no', $booking_id_no)
->where(DATE(tb.booking_date),DATE(tras.assign_time))
->get()
->row();
```

The issue is the following line
            ->where(Dat(tb.booking_date),DATE(tras.assign_time)) 
because when I commented it out I got some data

Please HELP

Comment: Try to edit this line `->where(Dat(tb.booking_date),DATE(tras.assign_time))` to this: `->where('DATE(tb.booking_date)','DATE(tras.assign_time)')`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, the error persisted. thank you for your comment

Comment: Does your `raw` sql query provide desired result?

Comment: Yes, i got desired data @SergheiLeonenco

Comment: Change your where to this exactly: `->where('DATE(tb.booking_date)','DATE(tras.assign_time)')` make sure that you keep your dates in single-column on both sides. Like `'DATE(tb.booking_date)'` and `'DATE(tras.assign_time)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. ([Source](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id2))

So change your code to following

```
$this->where('DATE(tb.booking_date)','DATE(tras.assign_time)', false)
```